# Correct value for Yocto KMACHINE setting

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to find the correct value for the [`KMACHINE`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-KMACHINE) setting, defined as "The machine as known by the kernel."

When I manually configure the kernel (outside of Yocto) I do not enter a machine type. I do set `ARCH=arm`, choose a "system type" config option like `CONFIG_ARCH_LPC32XX=y`, or load a defconfig like `lpc32xx_defconfig` but I don't know if any of those is what `KMACHINE` is supposed to be.

As an example, the Yocto documentation gives `intel-core2-32` which does not appear anywhere the Linux 5.15 sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KMACHINE` is used to select Yocto-specific metadata for building the kernel, and is not passed to the kernel build system. By default, it is set to `${MACHINE}` in `kernel-yocto.bbclass`, and can be overridden if a machine does not need its own metadata selection, and can instead use an existing metadata.

There's a better description under `LINUX_KERNEL_TYPE` in the manual (paraphrased):

> The KMACHINE and LINUX_KERNEL_TYPE variables define the search arguments used by Yocto's kernel tools to find the appropriate description within Yocto's kernel metadata with which to build out the kernel sources and configuration.

This [kernel metadata](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/advanced.html) is maintained by the Yocto Project, in the `yocto-kernel-cache` repository. It is optional, and is only used if the selected kernel recipe is a "linux-yocto" style recipe (i.e. it inherits `linux-yocto.inc`).

If you're using an out-of-kernel-tree `defconfig` to configure your kernel, it's unlikely you'll need Yocto's kernel metadata, and therefore don't need to override `KMACHINE`.